# How to add zf2 module from github to my application using zend eclipse pdt

Tags: php, json, eclipse, zend-framework2

I have installed zf2 skeleton application using Zend Eclipse PDT. Now i want to install "cgm/zf2-file-upload-examples" package from github. Now i am trying to install this package in my application using composer. I have added cgm/zf2-file-upload-examples" : "=1.0.0" to my composer.json and then trying to update dependencies it is very bad that it is not downloading any package and adding to my application. My Composer.json is :

```
    {
     "name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
       "description" : "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
   "require" : {
   "php" : ">=5.3.3",
   "zendframework/zendframework" : "2.3.*",
   "cgm/zf2-file-upload-examples" : "=1.0.0"
   },
   "keywords" : [ "framework", "zf2" ],
   "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
   "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/"
   }
```

Can anybody guide me that what wrong i am doing?
or how can i do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this instead:

```
"cgm/zf2-file-upload-examples": "dev-master"
```